# how to align all my li on one line?

Tags: html, css

my CSS

```
ul{
overflow:hidden;
}
li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

my HTML

```
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
<li>g</li>
</ul>
```

i want to align all my li items in one line, if i did that everything works fine except that when 3 or 4 li's fills the first line on my body they go the the second line, i want them to be on 1 line and everything after the 1 line is filled will be "hidden"

FOR EXAMPLE ::

// NOTE li holds sentences not just 1 letter

OUTPUT NOW ::

```
a               b                c              d
      e                  f               g
```

DESIRED OUTPUT ::

```
a                 b              c              d         e      f  //all of them in 1 line and the rest of them are hidden 'overflow:hidden'
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try putting `white-space:nowrap;` in your `<ul>` style

edit: and use 'inline' rather than 'inline-block' as other have pointed out (and I forgot)

Answer (score 20):

This works as you wish:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 

ul
{ 
overflow-x:hidden;
white-space:nowrap; 
height: 1em;
width: 100%;
} 

li
{ 
display:inline; 
}       
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul> 
<li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
<li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
<li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
<li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
<li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
<li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
<li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
</ul> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1, i tested the above snippet.It is working as expected: > http://jsbin.com/acaxo3/edit

Answer (score 9):

Using Display: table

HTML:

```
<ul class="my-row">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.my-row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.my-row > li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

SCSS:

```
ul {
  &.my-row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    
    > li {
      display: table-cell;
    }
  } 
}
```

Works great for me

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you want.  In this case you do not want the list items to be treated as blocks that can wrap.

```
li{display:inline}
ul{overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: if the desired effect is to have scrollbars to see the rest of the lin, the `overflow` should be `auto` -- `hidden` will cut the line off and the rest of it won't be seen on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm would recommend it:

```
<style>
    .clearfix {
       *zoom: 1;
    }
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    ul.list {
       list-style: none;
    }
    ul.list li {
       display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<ul class="list clearfix">
    <li>li-one</li>
    <li>li-two</li>
    <li>li-three</li>
    <li>li-four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please add some explenation to your answer? Simply showing code can be confusing for some people.

Answer (score 1):

Other than `white-space:nowrap;` also add the following CSS

```
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: underrated solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the NOBR tag might be overkill, and as you said, unreliable.

There are 2 options available depending on how you are displaying the text.

If you are displaying text in a table cell you would do Long Text Here. If you are using a div or a span, you can use the style="white-space: nowrap;"