# How to put two <li> items on one line [inline, float left, and inline block not working]

Tags: html, css

I am very new to html, css, javascript, php, and sql, so I tried to make a simple program to replicate a store's homepage. Here's the basic idea:

I wanted all my li items to all be on one line, however this didn't work, so I looked at: [how to align all my li on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325926/how-to-align-all-my-li-on-one-line) and changed display: inline to display: inline-block and added float: left and float: right, with the same html.

Then I looked at [How do I render <li> side-by-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918606/how-do-i-render-li-side-by-side), and took out the display: inline-block, which still didn't work, so I took out floats and added back in display: inline-block, which didn't work either.

Lastly I saw [Align two inline-blocks left and right on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272605/align-two-inline-blocks-left-and-right-on-same-line) and display: flex justify-content: space-between, which still didn't work.

How do I fix this?

Final code with flex and space-between:

```css
#header {
  background-color: purple;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
            
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
            
#navbar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>William Shop</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="register.php" class="register_link">Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="loginq.php" class="login_link">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have two `ul` elements? You should put both `li` in the same `ul`. Then use the answers from the questions you looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll try this

`<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Please place the li in the same ul. Look at the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tqasgr6x/

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="register.php" class="register_link">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="loginq.php" class="login_link">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


#header {
  background-color: purple;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having different `<ul>` will not be placed side by side. Unless you really want to place it side by side it is another story.

Anyway, here is an example of what you want to achieve: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0p6cub9v/)**

You just need to place the `display:inline-block` and `float:left` on the `<li>` so that you can place them side by side.

```
ul li{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will list in single line

css

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

single ul

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="register.php" class="register_link">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="loginq.php" class="login_link">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Use float for right alignment
[Refer](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)